# OpenMP in Fortran: Changes to data types?

Tags: types, fortran, openmp

I have a program which I once compile with and without OpenMP. Even when I run it with ONE input-file to convert with OMP_NUM_THREADS set to 1, the resulting ASCII files differs from the one which I get when I run the program, which is compiled without OpenMP! I really don't get it... "diff" in linux prints out every single line as different, but when I look into the file myself and compare the single float values, I don't see any difference myself.
The file looks like:

> 0.949566E+00  0.945844E+00  0.942125E+00  0.938410E+00  0.934698E+00
>     0.930989E+00  0.927285E+00  0.923584E+00  0.919888E+00  0.916196E+00
>     0.912508E+00  0.908826E+00  0.905149E+00  0.901476E+00  0.897810E+00
>     0.894149E+00  0.890493E+00  0.886845E+00  0.883202E+00  0.879565E+00

etc... (Currently running with single precision!)...
Is there any internal data-change in OpenMP or any advice on this?

Comment: OpenMP might change the order of calculations which might affect the result, but it does not change the internal data layout or precision.  If you are seeing a difference at the file level printing out these values, then I would suggest trying diff with -b or try cmp (and look at the the byte values with -b).

Comment: I don't think if you got me wrong or not: When I print out the values with vi, more, tail or something like that, I see NO difference. Neither in the order of the lines, nor in the values itself. But thanks, I'll try to check via -b flag :) Do you know any easy pipe-construction in linux to only check let's say the first 10 lines in diff? (The files have thousands of lines)... Thanks!

Comment: If not, I'll just redirect 10 lines of both files into new files via head -n file > newfile and than check newfile ;) Thanks!

Comment: ejd's completely right about the fact that compiling with omp can change things -- the compiler can't optimze across the boundary of a parallel section, for instance -- but I'm more fascinated by this bit: "`diff` in linux prints out every single line as different, but when I look into the file myself and compare the single float values, I don't see any difference myself."   This to me makes it sound like a formatting/whitespace issue.   Can you show us verbatim two lines that don't match, and the code for outputting?

Comment: Ah, your comments came ahead of mine.   xxdiff or tkdiff also pop up windows that explicitly show where in the lines the differences are, which will simplify spotting whitespace (say) issues.

Comment: Okay I'm completely confused now... When I run the converting with the openmp-binary twice, the result is twice the same (as it should be, but you can see, there's really an "order" to openmp processing), when comparing this one to the result I get with the original binary (without openmp) `cmp` gives me _only_ one "line" as different. But when I open the files in vi and scroll to that line, I see that the following lines also differ! strangly the lines bevor this certain line (it's at 40% of the file at line 619882) don't seem to differ (I checked the last 20 before)... Completely confused!:(

Comment: "By default, cmp is silent if the files are the same; if they differ, the byte and line number at which the first difference occurred is reported".  That is why I suggested using it - though if you have access to something like xxdiff or tkdiff you might feel better since you will see all the differences.

Comment: Yeah thanks, unfortunality I haven't... So any advice how to handle it? I can't see any wrong piece of code in the source which is compiled with OpenMP (actually, there are no changes to loops or data-declarations or variable-definitions except for the !$OMP directives) that's why I have no clue on how to look further into the problem...

Comment: Common problems are incorrect scoping and data races.  Another thing that can change results is if you are using reduction clauses.  The nice thing is that you can remove directives easily by getting rid of the "$" in the directive and that makes it a comment.  Remove directives and make runs until you have limited it down to the directive causing the problem.  Then you will have to look at variable scoping and see if there is a problem.  Also, remember, just because the values are different doesn't mean that you actually have a problem (the same thing can be true for serial code as well).

Comment: "Also, remember, just because the values are different doesn't mean that you actually have a problem (the same thing can be true for serial code as well)." why? Now the thing is, I only have ONE parallel/do-clause with default(private) and some shared-vars ... One question: When I have some do-loops within the do-loop which should get parallelized, the internal do-loops certainly WON'T get parallelized, right? Because if they would, I would need to use some "ordered"-directive here I think.

Comment: There are two points which I don't know are correct or not: First of all, in every loop files get read and written, so I assign my file-handles a different unit number each time like F_RES=25+i where i is the loop-variable. Is this approach correct? Second thing is: In the loop there's a subroutine call. The subroutine is coded into a different .f-file with additional variable-definitions etc. Could that make things mess up?

Comment: maybe, you could post some actual code instead of describing it???

Comment: OpenMP can change the order of the calculations. Depending on the value range of the numbers involved this can make a difference (one of the posts has a long discussion on this). In any case, this same thing can be seen in serial programs, if for example, you change a loop that goes from 1 to N to a loop that goes from N to 1. Unfortunately, since you haven't given use anything to look at it is very hard to say what the problem is.

Comment: As for your following questions, any of the things that you have listed could make a difference.  OpenMP has a set of "default" rules for variables in subroutines.  They could be shared depending on how you declared them and that could cause problems.  As for I/O from a thread, you can't read/write from/to a file from multiple threads without a problem.  Each thread needs to have a different unit number and different file if you want things to work or you need to "lock" around the I/O.  As for loops inside a parallel workshare do, they are run by the thread assigned the outer chunk of work.